# Condition with radiobutton checked don't work

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons in fieldset. I'm try to apply condition if the second radio is checked, but it doesn't work. If I get the two elements by ID using firebug console, it says that the 2 elements are checked.

My code:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="radio" name="soci1" id="sisoci1" value="soci1"/>
    <label for="sisoci1">Soci/Abonat</label>

    <input type="radio" name="soci1" id="nosoci1" value="nosoci1"/>
    <label for="nosoci1">Convidat</label>
</fieldset>
```

My function:

```
  if(document.getElementById("nosoci1").checked=true){
        check_soci1="no_soci";
    }else{
        check_soci1="soci";
    }
```

What the firebug says:

```
  >>> document.getElementById("sisoci1")
    <input id="sisoci1" type="radio" value="soci1" name="soci1" checked="checked">
    >>> document.getElementById("nosoci1")
    <input id="nosoci1" type="radio" value="nosoci1" name="soci1" checked="checked">
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: == is comparation, with = you set checked value to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use comparison, you need double `==` sign:

```
if(document.getElementById("nosoci1").checked == true) { ... }
```

Or just skip the comparison altogether:

```
if(document.getElementById("nosoci1").checked) { ... }
```

The way your code is written, with single `=` sign, 'checked' property is assigned the value of `true` and then `if` comparison is executed on that value - effectively always evaluating to `true`.

Comment: OMFG, WTF. I'm so stupid... today I'm more asleep than ever... Thanks so much for solve my newbie error!